# Python How to skip empty lines when reading a text file

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to solve a question from `Introduction to data science` on coursera:

> Returns a DataFrame of towns and the states they are in from the
> university_towns.txt list. The format of the DataFrame should be:
> DataFrame( [ ["Michigan", "Ann Arbor"], ["Michigan", "Yipsilanti"] ],
> columns=["State", "RegionName"]  )
>
> ```
> The following cleaning needs to be done:
>
> 1. For "State", removing characters from "[" to the end.
> 2. For "RegionName", when applicable, removing every character from " (" to the end.
> 3. Depending on how you read the data, you may need to remove newline character '\n'.
> ```

My script was like the following:

```
uni_towns = pd.read_csv('university_towns.txt', header=None, names={'RegionName'})
uni_towns['State'] = np.where(uni_towns['RegionName'].str.contains('edit'), uni_towns['RegionName'], '')
uni_towns['State'] = uni_towns['State'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
import re
# Removing (...) from state names
uni_towns['RegionName'] = uni_towns['RegionName'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', x))
split_string = "("
uni_towns['RegionName'] = uni_towns['RegionName'].apply(lambda x: x.split(split_string, 1)[0])
# Removing [...] from state names
uni_towns['RegionName'] = uni_towns['RegionName'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', '', x))
uni_towns['State'] = uni_towns['State'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', '', x))
uni_towns = pd.DataFrame(uni_towns,columns = ['State','RegionName']).sort_values(by=['State', 'RegionName'])
return uni_towns
```

The first line is obsviously about reading the text file, then all fields in `RegionName` that contains the word `edit` are states as well:

```
uni_towns['State'] = np.where(uni_towns['RegionName'].str.contains('edit'), uni_towns['RegionName'], '')
```

Then I am removing everything between parentheses () and square brackets [] from each of `RegionName` rows:

```
uni_towns['RegionName'] = uni_towns['RegionName'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', x))

uni_towns['RegionName'] = uni_towns['RegionName'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', '', x))
```

So if a value was like `Alabama[edit]` or `Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama)`, they will become, `Alabama` and `Tuscaloosa`.

Then I am doing the same thing for the `State` columns, as I moved some values from `RegionName` into it if it contains `[edit]`.

I am using the following because there is few rows having something like ``Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama`where there is only`(` and it wasn't detected by the regex pattern:

```
uni_towns['RegionName'] = uni_towns['RegionName'].apply(lambda x: x.split(split_string, 1)[0])
```

The final result is: `567 rows × 2 columns`

> State RegionName
>
> 0 Alabama Alabama
>
> 1 Alabama Auburn
>
> 2 Alabama Florence
>
> 3 Alabama Jacksonville
>
> ...
>
> 564   Wisconsin   Whitewater
>
> 551   Wisconsin   Wisconsin
>
> 566   Wyoming Laramie
>
> 565   Wyoming Wyoming

**While the correct result should be `517 rows x 2 columns.**

After looking into the `txt` file, I saw that some of the rows are taking 2 consecutive lines with `\n` when read, but the script is not detecting that the second line before `\n` is still within the same row.

Here is [the text content](https://github.com/irJERAD/Intro-to-Data-Science-in-Python/blob/master/MyNotebooks/university_towns.txt).

Answer (score 0):

The [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) shows that the `read_csv` function has a `skip_blank_lines` option. So you could add `skip_blank_lines=True` to to `read_csv` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
last_data=[]
for line in lines:
  last_data.append(line.strip("\n") # so it will remove any new lines comes last of string

# or you can say if line equals "\n" continue
```